# check to see if a user is on an ios device with jquery

Tags: jquery, user-agent

I have seen versions of this question asked before but there are always conflicting answers and they are a few years old. Some people say using user agent is iffy so I'm wondering what a better solution would be. I need to find out if a user is on an ios device and if not direct them to a page that says something like please open this link on a ios device and so on.

Comment: Did you try using one you already found on other versions? `if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {` seems promising though..

Comment: that does work but some people suggest not using user agent so I'm wondering if it is acceptable to use

Comment: Any specific reason why they said not to use?

Comment: some people say user-agents are not really reliable since they can be changed or some say user agent strings are changing and getting updated as new phones and brands are coming day by day

Comment: Agreed.. But AFAIK, no issues reported so far.. Well not even having knowledge whether there's any replacement for the same..

Comment: I guess I'll use that for now and see if I run into any problems in the future

Comment: yea sure.. Do let know if you face any problem..